# Cannot read and write the query result back to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using `BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(...)` to read rows from BigQuery then writing `TableRow` back to BigQuery using `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()`. I have table with correct schema already created so using `CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER` and will not have to set schema in Beam client. Problem is that the all `Record` fields are flattened(underscore appended) in query result and does not match the schema of the table which is not in flattened form. Using `.withoutResultFlattening()` on reads did not help unflattening the Records so cannot get around this discrepancy. How do we query without flattening the result?

Comment: I'm from GCP Support team and we could test that `.withoutResultFlattening()` worked fine from our side. Could you please add some logging immediately after BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery().withoutResultFlattening() to ensure that the rows are not being flattened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Standard SQL since the results will not be flattened as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#structure_of_selected_nested_leaf_fields).